# How to identify an element in selenium even if xpath is same

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I am new to selenium and trying to autoamte a web application in junit framework. As many get some problem in identifying web elements,I too stuck at a point where two submit buttons are having same xpath and css selector.

The only difference what I can observe is.. In the two form tags, I can see that className is different(for first form tag it is `"feature_space_checkbox"` and for second form tag it is "`auto_fs_steps_checkbox"`)

As, I need to identify the second submit button..So I tried to identify the second submit button as below

```
driver.findElement(new ByChained(By.className("auto_fs_steps_checkbox"),By.xpath("//*[@id='edit_brochure_2863']/input[3]")));
```

When I try to execute this, I got the error as

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.chained({By.className: auto_fs_steps_checkbox,By.xpath: //*[@id='edit_brochure_2863']/input[3]})
```

Can anyone please correct me where I made the mistake

Adding DOM for this scenario

```
<form action="/brochures/2865/feature_space_checked" class="feature_space_checkbox" id="edit_brochure_2865" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

For the second submit button it is..

```
<form action="/brochures/2865/update_auto_fs_steps" class="auto_fs_steps_checkbox" id="edit_brochure_2865" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, XPath and CSS selectors are not definitive. There are many XPath and CSS for every element on a page so to say they have the same Xpath and CSS selectors is incorrect.

For your example, is there any need to use XPath or combine two selectors?

The following CSS would work;

```
form.auto_fs_steps_checkbox input
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use chaining as this can all be expressed in XPath:

```
//*[@id='edit_brochure_2863' and @class='feature_space_checkbox']/input
```

So this will be in Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edit_brochure_2863' and @class='feature_space_checkbox']/input"));
```

Of course, for the second submit button it will be

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edit_brochure_2863' and @class='auto_fs_steps_checkbox']/input"));
```

Comment: "Class=" is always risky in xpath as it treats class as a literal string. Unlike CSS selectors, if a extra class was added to the element, the xpath would no longer work. Even order cannot be guaranteed so "class='foo bar"' would be potentially unstable as it would not match "bar foo".  I would always try to use "contains(@class, "foo")" as this would still work even if a class was added

Comment: @RobbieWareham your warning is certainly true and justified. However, I did it on purpose and was aware of the problem. The OP specified the XML clearly and there is no other class present, so for this _specific_ problem it does work.

Comment: Yes, but HTML is often dynamic especially classes, so just wanted to point out the alternative.  BTW I have no issues with XPath, infact I think it is often misunderstood and malined

Answer (score 0):

xpath for the second submit would be

```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@class='auto_fs_steps_checkbox']/input"));
```

This is enough to identify the second button as here class name is unique and id is same for both. So its better we do it by class name .